# Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: angular, archivo, fileupload, formdata

Estoy trabajando en Angular e intento enviar un video (File) en un POST.

El error que tengo es el siguiente:

**TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.**

El objecto que tengo es este:

```
File { end:5806551, lastModified:1561776293000, lastModifiedDate:1561776293000, localURL:"cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Video/Sent/VID-20190628-WA0032.mp4", name:"VID-20190628-WA0032.mp4", size:5806551, start:0, type:"video/mp4", __proto__: ... }
```

Intente añadir el archivo al formulario de las siguientes dos formas pero ambas dicen el mismo error de que el archivo no es un Blob.

```
// formData.append('recipeVideo', this.current_video);
formData.append('recipeVideo', this.current_video, 'recipe_video.' + this.current_video.type.split('/')[1]);
```

De ser extrictamente necesario que sea blob, ¿existe una forma de convertir un File a Blob?.

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Daniel. `File` es compatible con `Blob`. Por favor revisa que verdaderamente estés mandando un dato al `formData` antes del `append`. Puedes usar algo como `miVideo instanceof File`.

Comment: @Angel voy a probar lo que me dices, te respondo a ver como me va, gracias!

Comment: Intenta también solo con los dos primeros parámetros.

Comment: @Angel fue error mio, creí haber probado añadiendo el archivo de la primera forma que tenia comentada arriba, ahora lo hice realmente y funciono. Muchas gracias

Comment: Me da gusto que lo solucionaste y bienvenido. Espero verte por acá seguido.